# AV(Queued)Player seekToTime: jumping to zero

Tags: macos, avfoundation, soundcloud, avplayer

I am using an AVQueuedPlayer to playback SoudCloud files. If I use seekToTime:(CMTime)time on the AVQueuedPlayer the player just jumps to 0 and starts playing again. Any ideas how to fix this?
I tried to paste the MP3 URL into other players and all of them can seek, so it does not seem to be an server issue.

Bests,
Philip

Comment: Why are you down voting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK to make this clear: You should use something like this:

```
- (void)advanceToTime:(float)timeToGo {
int32_t timeScale = self.audioPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale;
CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(timeToGo, timeScale);
[self.audioPlayer seekToTime:time completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Finished %@",finished ? @"NO" : @"YES");
}];
}
```